# What glasses are meant for which beers and why?

Tags: glassware

I know there are already one or two questions that touch on specific beers. However, I would like more of a comprehensive list. I would also like to understand why those types of glasses are chosen. Is it for head retention? Breathability? Appearances?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Function

Beer glassware serves a few primary purposes:

- it is part of the branding of the beer (for beers with their own glass)
- it presents the beer (beauty is in the eye of the beer holder) showcasing the beer's color, clarity and/or carbonation.
- it influences how quickly volatiles (aromatics) are released
- it influences how much beer can be consumed per sip (e.g. compare champagne flute vs. beer mug)
- it can promote head retention (through the shape, plus small etchings in the base of the glass)

### Some examples

- A Pilsner glass is a long tall V-shaped glass. It emphasizes the
  color, clarity and effervescence of the Pilsner. It's similar in
  principle to the fluted champagne glass, but having larger rim,
  affords larger sips.
- The traditional mug is a robust glass, primarly aimed at "chinking"
  glasses together and allowing large swallows of beer.
- The challace/goblet can be beautiful pieces of work, designed to
  showcase the beer, and also promote and maintain a large head.
- The tulip glass captures volatiles (in the narrow part of the glass)
  while the large opening at the top supports a large head.
- The Sniffer, typically used for cognac/brandy, but also for very
  strong ales, has a large base that curves up to a small opening to
  capture the aromatics, and to allow for swirling to encourage more
  aromatics to be released.
- The Stange, a long tall glass, amplifies the malt and hop
  characteristics by concentrating them in a smaller area, while also
  providing a simple elegant presentation of the beer. Often used with
  delicate beers.
- The Weizen glass is similar to the pilsner glass, but larger
  (typically 0.5l minimum) with plenty of room for the large head
  typical of a wheat beer.

For more details and images, see [Glassware for Beer](http://beeradvocate.com/beer/101/glassware/).

Comment: Consider making this post community wiki; this way everyone can build upon it and create a much more comprehensive list. Thanks!